# This is the error I am getting at the time of start Hadoop in Mac environment

Tags: hadoop, configuration

[image]

This image showss the error while running the following code:

```
$ hadoop fs -ls
```

on terminal

Comment: Don't use a screencap for what is text information. Put error messages and code into the question itself as text. See [ask]. [Edit] the question and tell us what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` isn't set correctly or contains all the necessary files.

The start of the highlight is only a warning

You should be able to at least get some output from this rather than an error

```
ls $HADOOP_CONF_DIR/core-site.xml
```